# Google Sheets API v4 - downloading/saving charts

Tags: google-sheets-api

Is it possible to download a chart from a google sheet using the API? I don't see any reference in the docs that describe how to save a chart to an image file.

Comment: As an image, I don't think it is immediately possible. You can acquire chart [*information*](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts#read_chart_data), which would let you create the chart locally (by requesting the `values` resource for the various source ranges), or you could add the chart as its own `Sheet` and then use your preferred method to export that particular sheet as a PDF or image.

Comment: Unfortunately, the charts in spreadsheet cannot be directly retrieved by Sheets API as an image. So as a workaround, how about retrieving the chart as an image using Web Apps which returns the image blob of the chart in spreadsheet? In this case, you are required to use Google Apps Script. But you can call the deployed Web Apps using various languages you want. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestions.