# How to download charts in PNG from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am trying to create a custom menu in Google Sheet to allow me download all charts in all worksheets in current Google Sheet file into PNG images, using the chart title as image names, saving into the default download directory of my Windows PC.

I was going to do it in Python use Google Sheet API and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51250096/google-sheets-api-v4-downloading-saving-charts), the answer basically said that I may be able to do it with Google Apps Script.

I found a [Google Apps Scripts example](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-5/#3) explaining how to export a chart into a slide, but can't figure out how to download a chart as PNG file.

Is this even possible?

If yes, could anyone please point me to the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### Approach:

You can get the charts from your document with the function `getCharts()`, transform them into an image with the function `getAs()` and then obtain the link from Google Drive.

### Snippet

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

  // create a proxy slide
  var proxySlide = SlidesApp.create("proxySlide");
  var proxySaveSlide = proxySlide.getSlides()[0];
  var chartImage = proxySaveSlide.insertSheetsChartAsImage(chart);

  // Get image from slides
  var myimage = chartImage.getAs('image/png');
  var url = DriveApp.createFile(myimage).getUrl();

  // delete the proxy slide
  DriveApp.getFileById(proxySlide.getId()).setTrashed(true);

  return url;
}
```

### Refernece

[Blob Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob)

Comment: Thank you @Alessandro, This works as it intended! However, the image quality seems to be lower from a direct manual save as PNG. Also the chart comes with customized chart styles, i.e. line width, point size, etc., The getAs() function doesn't seem to preserve those customizations. If there is a way to get image the same as a direct manual download, would you please point me to that direction? Thanks again!

Comment: I see, I found that this doesn't happen on slides for example. You could use a slide presentation as a proxy to save your chart there as an image and eventually get the URL from Drive in the same way as before.