# How to save a googlesheet chart as image by Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, gspread

I'm using Googlesheet API with Python and I can get access to the sheet and the cells now. However, I don't know how to get the chart in the sheet.

```
client = gspread.service_account_from_dict(creds)
workbook = client.open('HR - 8/16-8/31 Data')
sheet = workbook.get_worksheet(0)
H1 = sheet.acell('B3').value
```

I found this question:[How to download charts in PNG from google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61491782/how-to-download-charts-in-png-from-google-sheet) mentioned I can use the `getCharts()` function, but it is for JavaScript only. If there a similar function in Python?

Comment: getCharts is available in Google Javascript SDK but not in python

Comment: @ag7-alexis You're right! Do you know if there is a similar function in Python?

Comment: @Mary the [documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.4.0/) has no comment on chart or image capture from spreadsheet. Probably the best solution is to load the data in pandas DataFrame and do your own chart in matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the API doesn't have a method to do this. The charts overview [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/charts) explains how to manipulate and create them, but not how to export them. Reading the data also only gives you a JSON representation of it, not an image. It seems that the Apps Script `getCharts()` leverages other server-side functions that are not in the regular API.

This is documented as a feature request in Google's issue tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/230039395), so you can +1 it if you want. In that thread a possible workaround was posted. If you [publish](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965) your file you can build a URL if you know the `chartID` to generate it as an image:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/<publish-id>/pubchart?oid=<chart-id>&format=image
```

Gspread doesn't seem to have methods to do this so you'll have to use the Google APIs. In their [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/python) you can find a sample to set up authorization, and you can use [`spreadsheets.get()`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html#get), which gives you all the data from the spreadsheet including the chart IDs. If you only have a single chart that you want to export periodically then you can just get the ID once from the UI and just retrieve it with Python. The caveat is that you have to publish the Sheet which you don't want to do with sensitive information.

As another alternative you could build an Apps Script [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) which uses the [`getCharts()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getcharts) method in the answer that you linked, and just send a POST message from your Python app and have Apps Script return the image in its response.